# Author Field empty when saving a new Document in Word 2010

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I use Office 2010 on a Windows XP SP3 machine.
When saving a Document, either be a new or edited one, neither the "Author", nor the "LastSavedBy" properties get written.
Since i made a new .docx the privacy option that removes all personal data is not the root of this error because this setting only applies to documents opened in compatibility mode, right?

Answer (score 0):

> this setting only applies to documents opened in compatibility mode, right?

Not AFAICS - if you have a compatibility mode .docx and it already has this option checked, when you save as a .docx and do not check the compatibility mode option, then re-open, the option is still checked. If you uncheck it, then re-save, the option is then greyed out.

So if you created your new .docx that way, that might explain what you are seeing. But if the setting is greyed out, something else must be going on.

AFAIK the availability of that checkbox is determined by a setting you could look for in your .docx - Make a copy of your .docx, add .zip to the name, open the .zip, then the "word" folder, then open settings.xml and look for something like "w:removePersonalInformation". If it's there, you should be able to check/uncheck the privacy setting. If it's not, the setting should be greyed out.

Comment: the setting is greyed out

Comment: what about the w:removePersonalInformation value in settings.xml ? (I've just edited my previous text so you should be able to see what to look for).

Comment: Opened the container and unfortunately couldn't find the `<w:removePersonalInformation>` tag in `settings.xml` so i assume it's not set, what would very well blend with the fact that the setting is greyed out.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the error on my RDServer (W2k8R2) and the properties got written. So this may either be a general issue with WinXP SP3 (what i can't quite imagine) or a malconfiguration of my word installation. So every hint that points me in a helpful direction is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any suggestions ither than to follow general-purpose troubleshooting procedures. With Word, I generally start by finding and saving/renaming Word's "data key" in the Windows registry, deleting it, then restarting Word to see if the problem has gone away.